# Equivalence relation among matrices

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider the set of $p\times q$ matrices with entries from the set $S=\{1,\dots,s\}$. Say that two such matrices are *equivalent* if one can be transformed into the other by a series of operations of the form:

1. Permute the rows.
2. Permute the columns.
3. Permute $S$.

I'm interested in knowing:

a) Is there a name for this relation?

b) What are its applications?

c) Is there an efficient algorithm for finding the lexicographically smallest matrix in a class?

---

**Addition.** I have realized now that if the matrix is a *Latin square* (and thus represents a *quasi-group*) this is precisely the definition of *isotopy.* So I guess that answers a) and part of b).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by permute $S$? Swap any two entries $s_{ij}$ and $s_{mn}$

Comment: @dexter04 I think OP refers to taking a permutation of the set of symbols in $S$.

Comment: @dexter04: To replace each entry $x$ by $\sigma(x)$ for some permutation $\sigma$ of $S$.